# Connection must be valid and open error

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm getting error: Connection must be valid and open when I start this program. I searched on google and only found 2 people that have the same error. Is it possible to fix this ?? Thx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.Sql;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=******;Database=testing;";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();

        string insertQuery = "ALTER TABLE `user` ADD lol INT";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(insertQuery);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why did you put the odbc tag ? This question has nothing to do with ODBC...

Comment: Hey, you asked the same thing one hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232943/database-query-c-not-working

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to tell your command about your connection object.
Add the connection parameter to this line:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your command has no connection assignet to it. Try passing the connection to the the command's constructor like this:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
```