# Connection must be valid and open asp .net core

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core

This is my IActionResult, I'm working with MySQL, its supposed to make a user register, but for some reason everytime I try to execute it, I get the message "Connection must be valid and open" I've checked the connection string and it's valid, and I also open it, could anyone help me out?

Yes, I know this is prone to SQL Injection, so no need to tell me that.

```
 public IActionResult Maak()
        {
            string conn = "server=localhost;user id=Job;password=SamplePassword;database=kingdom_of_uluth";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            string userName = HttpContext.Request.Query["usernamesignup"];
            string password = HttpContext.Request.Query["passwordsignup"];
            con.ConnectionString = conn;
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand($"INSERT INTO account(username, password, lastlogin) VALUES({userName}, {password}, now());");
                com.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            con.Close();
            return View("RegisterOK");
        }
```

I've tried the solution that has been suggested by Henk Mollema, but then I get another error which is

> Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
>   Unknown column 'asdasd' in 'field list'

in which asdasd is the username I put in the username field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection must be valid and open error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233185/connection-must-be-valid-and-open-error)

Comment: @HenkMollema tried it, still didnt work. edited the question thou

Comment: Try adding quotes around the values in the `VALUES (...)` statement. E.g. `'{userName}'`. You wouldn't have this problem though if you'd just use proper command parameters for your query using `com.Parameters.AddWithValue()` rather than concatenating the values in the query.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code snippet:

1. The connection object should be passed to the command object to associate the command with the connection, e.g.:

```cs
MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("your query", con);
```

See [Connection must be valid and open error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233185/connection-must-be-valid-and-open-error) as well.

2. You're missing quotes around the values in the `VALUES (...)` statement in the SQL query, for example `'{userName}'`. You wouldn't have this problem though if you'd just use proper command parameters for your query using `com.Parameters.AddWithValue()` rather than concatenating the values in the query which enables SQL injection.